# AngularJS use ng-options to create a Set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data-model that looks like the following (there are other fields but these are the most significant):

```
$scope.model = [ 
    {
        id: 1, 
        country: "US"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        country: "UK"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        country: "DE"
    },   
    {
        id: 4,
        country: "DE"
    },    
    {
        id: 5,
        country: "DE"
    },    
    {
        id: 6,
        country: "US'
    },    
]
```

I want to get the following array:

```
[ "US", "UK", "DE"]
```

in order to show it in a `<select>` something like the following:

```
<select ng-model="myList" ng-options="m.country for m in model | somefilter "><select>
```

unique isnt convenient since it does exactly the opposite of what I want.

Comment: how does `ng-options` do the oposite of what you want: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I believe he needs to get unique country properties for the options. I don't see how it can be done without creating an extra object / array first (and getting the ng-options values from there)

Comment: @alou, wouldn't `| unique : 'country'` work in this case?

Comment: most probably, yes, I wasn't thinking :/

Comment: @alou, no problem, my typical problem with angular is that the obvious solution to a problem is never the "Angular Way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/HB7LU/6296/)

Unless I'm misinterpreting the question you want to filter by unique properties of the objects in your model array.
The unique filter does this by passing in the property key:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="m.country for m in model | unique: 'country'">
  <option value="">choose country</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, i think you need to create a new scope var with the select options, getting the unique values of the initial object - in whatever iteration you'll be doing, you must have something to compare the values. So, something like that should do it:

```
$scope.countryOptions = [];
for(var i=0;i<$scope.model.length;i++){
    if($scope.countryOptions.indexOf($scope.model[i].country) === -1){
        $scope.countryOptions.push($scope.model[i].country);
    }
}
```

now you will be using `countryOptions` in the ng-options, to get the unique values

```
<select ng-model="myList" ng-options="item in countryOptions"><select>
```